# Rails - how to protect an attribute against updating from outside of the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

In Rails 5 I have a model with an attribute, value of which is never set directly but is always calculated in `before_save` callback instead. I would like to protect this attribute from being updated from outside of the model, so that calls like f. e. `update_attribute()` would fail. I used `attr_readonly` inside the model to achieve what I want and it worked great until I realised that it prevents *all* updates! Also from within the model itself. Since, according to [Rails API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ReadonlyAttributes/ClassMethods.html) this is the correct behaviour, what would be the best way to reject modifications to a particular attribute but only from the outside?

Answer (score 1):

You could override the setter. On the model:

```
def protected_attr_name=(val)
  # raise SomeException
end
```

This disables:

```
model.protected_attr_name = "value"  # => raise exception
model.update_attributes(protected_attr_name: "value")  # => raise exception
```

And then in your `before_save` method/block:

```
write_attribute(:protected_attr_name, calculated_value)
```

---

#### Additional observations

Like `attr_readonly`, you could choose to not raise an exception, and not do anything instead. This may be confusing/frustrating to others working on the same codebase, and is potentially very non-obvious behaviour.

Also - if it is *always* calculated in the `before_save`, consider whether this protection is necessary, or whether clearer attribute naming can effectively make the issue go away.

Comment: I was just about to write this answer myself.. I'll contribute with a link instead! http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ReadonlyAttributes/ClassMethods/attr_readonly

Comment: @FrederikSpang - the link unfortunately doesn't add anything new to the subject.

Comment: @gwcodes - that's interesting. While I obviously knew that I could override the setter, I didn't know how to bypass such custom setter from within the model, So you say that that `write_attribute()` is a viable method for bypass such custom setter only from inside of the model and won't work from the outside? Hm, need to double-check this. BTW - with `attr_readonly` I do get an exception thrown when doing `update_attribute()`. I'd like to keep it that way.

Comment: @silverdr: it's not so much that `write_attribute` won't work from outside the model, but rather that it prevents accidental update since someone using `write_attribute` needs to specifically employ it and deviate from established norms. Absolute protection is impractical, as `private` and `protected` are more guidelines than rules in Ruby... as long as you can update the attribute, another class can `send` a message to achieve the same thing.